# Can't register for event because function not marked as serializable. Can't mark function as serializable

Tags: .net, events, c++-cli

I have a function that I want to use as an event handler:

```
void singleFrameEventHandler(void) {
    SetEvent(g_hSingleFrameArrived);
}
```

However, when I try to register for the event:

```
iaframe->OnNewFrame += gcnew newFrame(&singleFrameEventHandler);
```

The following exception is raised:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Serialization of global methods (including implicit serialization via the use of asynchronous delegates) is not supported.

Is there some way to get around this?

---

Edit:

I have changed the code so now the event handler is a method in a class. However, now I get a different exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to find assembly 'BeamGage_Interface, Version=1.0.3882.24450, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

If it's relevant, the class definition looks like this:

```
[System::Serializable]
ref class FrameEventClass {
public:
    FrameEventClass(const char *newId, IAFrame ^ frame) : id(newId) {
        frame->OnNewFrame += gcnew newFrame(this, &FrameEventClass::frameEventHandler);
    }
private:
    const char *id;
    void frameEventHandler(void) {
        //Signal that the frame has arrived
        SetEvent(g_hSingleFrameArrived);
        //unregister for event
        IAFrame ^ frame = /* Code to get handle to frame object */;
        frame->OnNewFrame -= gcnew newFrame(this, &FrameEventClass::frameEventHandler);
        return;
    }
};
```

And here is how I register for the event:

```
gcnew FrameEventClass(id, iaframe);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Type 'FrameEventHandler' ... is not
>   marked as serializable

It's not referring to  your method `singleFrameEventHandler`, it's referring to the delegate type `FrameEventHandler`.

Probably something along the lines of `public delegate void FrameEventHandler();` in the code for assembly `BeamGage_Interface`.

**update for question update**
From [this page](http://electric-eye.info/csharp/polynomial-check-the-docs-on-the-mysql-site.html) (can't find the referenced msdn page)

> The common language runtime does not
>   support serialization of global
>   methods, so delegates cannot be used
>   to execute global methods in other
>   application domains.

Other CLR languages (c# etc) don't support global methods so you can't use them with the CLR. 
 Your solution (I believe) is to wrap `singleFrameEventHandler` (or maybe `g_hSingleFrameArrived`, I can't tell from your snippets) in a class and pass the instance method instead. Something like (forgive my lack of recent c++ usage, I may make mistakes)

```
class MyFrameEventHandler
{
    public:
        void singleFrameEventHandler(void){
            SetEvent(g_hSingleFrameArrived);
        }
}
// Usage
MyFrameEventHandler handler;
iaframe->OnNewFrame += gcnew newFrame(&handler.singleFrameEventHandler);
```

Comment: Alright, it turns out I was debugging a different version of the code than what I was editing and building. I edited the post to reflect the exception that is being raised due to my current code.